# CSS selectors - How can I individually select the spans inside my container?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to select each individual `span` inside my `.card--container` but I'm unable to do it. I have tried `:nth-of-type` `:nth-child`, but I'm missing something essential.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/intercoder/pen/f2e09646065a48cdbea41407233e9953/?editors=1100)

And this is my inline code.

```
<ul class="card--container">
  <li class="card">
    <header class="card__header">
      <h1>
        <a href="" class="card__link">Repo Title</a>
      </h1>
      <span>Pink</span>
    </header>
    <p class="card__content">Repo Content</p>
    <footer class="card__footer">Footer</footer>
  </li>
  
  <li class="card">
    <header class="card__header">
      <h1>
        <a href="" class="card__link">Repo Title</a>
      </h1>
      <span>Gray</span>
    </header>
    <p class="card__content">Repo Content</p>
    <footer class="card__footer">Footer</footer>
  </li>
  
  <li class="card">
    <header class="card__header">
      <h1>
        <a href="" class="card__link">Repo Title</a>
      </h1>
      <span>Green</span>
    </header>
    <p class="card__content">Repo Content</p>
    <footer class="card__footer">Footer</footer>
  </li>
</ul>

<p>Comment out <code>animation:sideLeft</code> and add <code>opacity: 1</code> on the <code>.card</code> to make debug easier.
```

```
/// Mixins
/// @name Size Mixin
/// @param { Number } $width - Width
/// @param { Number } $height - $width
@mixin size($width, $height: $width) {
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
}

@mixin keyframes($name) {
    @keyframes #{$name} {
      @content;
    }
}


/// @name Flex Mixin
/// @param { String } $flow 
/// @param { String } $justify
/// @param { String } $alingnment
@mixin display-flex($args...) {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: nth($args, 1); /*1*/
  justify-content: nth($args, 2); /*2*/
  align-items: nth($args, 3); /*3*/
}


/// Variables
$gray: hsla(0, 0%, 88.6%, 1);
$black: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);
$white: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1);
$blue: hsla(300, 47%, 75%, 1);
$yellow: hsla(60, 46.9%, 74.9%, 1);

$color-primary: hsla(300, 47%, 75%, 1); /* #dda1dd */
$color-secondary: hsla(150, 47%, 75%, 1); /* #a1ddbf */

body, html {
  background: $white;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid $color-primary;
};

p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: $color-primary;
}

.card--container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  @include size(90vw, 500px);
  border: 2px solid $gray;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card {
  @include display-flex(column, space-around, stretch);
  @include size(400px, 150px);
  opacity: 0;
  border: 2px solid $gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shdow: 3px 3px 3px 5px $gray;
  @include keyframes(slideLeft) {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(1500px);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }
  @for $i from 0 through 4 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      animation: slideLeft;
      animation-duration: 1s + ($i * 400ms);
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-delay: 1.5s + ($i * 400ms);
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    } 
  }
  
  &__header {
    @include display-flex(row, space-around, center);
    flex-basis: 25%;
    
     h1 {
      @include size(90%);
      letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    }
    
     span {  /* ERROR Here Will like to select each individual span */
      @include size(15px, 15px);
      border-radius: 100%;
      background-color: $color-primary;
      text-align: center;      
    }
  }
  
  &__link {
    color: $gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  
  &__content {
    color: $gray;
    font-size: 2em;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    text-align: center; 
  }
  
    
  &__footer {
    @extend .card__header;
    color: $gray;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply **different** styles to every span, you actually can select them using the `:nth-of-type(n)` pseudo-selector. What you do have to remember is that this pseudo-selector cannot be used on classes, so it will take the element instead of it. Fortunately, this element (`li`) is unique in your case.

```
.card--container {
    li:nth-of-type(1) span {
        background-color: #F00;
    }
    li:nth-of-type(2) span {
        background-color: #0F0;
    }
    li:nth-of-type(3) span {
        background-color: #00F;
    }
}
```

I've updated your codepen with a working example,

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/pNpGPr)

Comment: You forgot to add the hyper link

Comment: @TheWandererr I found out the hard way that I couldn't fork his codepen, so I had to recreate it, added and cheers for the heads up.

Comment: @Roberrrt that fixed it thanks, my question is why do I need to pass the `li`  element as wall and not just do `span:nth-of-type(){...}` inside my `.card` element (what I was trying to do before).

Comment: Because the actual span has no siblings that are also spans. They do not share the same parent. I use the card--container to restrain the code to this specific section, then the li items, that share the same parents, and select the spans inside of it :)

Comment: @Roberrrt thanks man, that clarified it. I ended up using `&:nth-of-type(n) span {...}` inside each of my `.card ` elements. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

To target each span the best thing to do would be to add an ID to each one and then add styles to that ID if you want them all to be different like so:

```
<span id="grey">Grey</span>

#grey {
   color: #808080;
}
```

or to target each span and have them inherit the same styles you could do:

```
.card span {
   color: #808080;
}
```

Comment: This is a solid answer, but i'm assuming OP doesn't want to use `ID`'s.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to use `:nth-of-type` :

```
.card-container li:nth-of-type(1) span {color: pink;}
.card-container li:nth-of-type(2) span {color: gray;}
.card-container li:nth-of-type(3) span {color: green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as below :

```
.card--container span{
<!-- CSS RULES-->
}
```

Comment: OP wishes to select every different CSS span with different rules.

Comment: Also, the class `.card__container` doesn't exist.